# How to create Smart Art in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer, drawing, flowchart

How do I create flow charts in LibreOffice writer? I know how to do it in Draw but I'd like to do it in Writer as well. (I'm looking for functionality close to Word's Smart Art feature)

Here's an example of what I mean and how it works in Word:

[image]

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend strongly either to use LibreOffice Draw or to use a full-fledged graph editor (e.g. [yEd graph editor](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_gallery.html)), and to embed the resulting chart into writer.

If you want to restrict yourself to the drawing abilities of LO Writer instead, you could use the [Drawing Tools](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Using_drawing_tools); you will find some flowchart objects using the "`Drawing`" toolbar (Menu "`View`" -> "`Toolbars`" -> "`Drawing`"):

[image]

[image]

But depending on your flowchart, you will soon find that using a different tool has some advantages; for example, you will have to connect the flowchart elements using lines manually, and you will have to adjust every connecting line or arrow manually if you move the flowchart element to another position. Other tools will adjust those connecting lines automatically.